# Ordenar Valores de uma Foreign Key em Django

Tags: django

Gostaria de saber se tem como ordenar os valores referentes a uma foreign key, que aparecem na hora de cadastrar por via de seleção.

```
class Curso(models.Model):

nome = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=False)
instituicao = models.ForeignKey(
    Instituicao, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='curso')
quantidade_semestres = models.CharField(
    max_length=2, choices=QUANTIDADE_SEMESTRES_CURSO_CHOICES, null = True)
carga_horaria = models.CharField(max_length=5, null=True, blank=True)

class Meta:
    db_table = "curso"

def __str__(self):
    return "%s - %s"%(self.nome,self.instituicao)
```

no caso, eu gostaria que os valores que aparecem em Instituição sejam listados de forma alfabética e não por ordem de inserção

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para realizar o que deseja precisa declarar isso no model Instituição, sendo algo do tipo:

```
class Instituicao(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["nome"]
```

Dessa maneira a FK será ordenada alfabeticamente pelo atributo nome.

Comment: Acredito que há um erro de digitação em `max_lenght`; não deveria ser `max_length`?

Comment: Justamente, corrigido, obrigado.